# what does typedef struct node *NODE indicate?

Tags: c

```
struct node
{
    int coef;

    int exp;

    struct node *link;
};

typedef struct node *NODE;
```

Comment: Please don't hide pointer types behind typedefs in real code though.

Comment: what would be the better way to write this code.In the book structure is used in 3 to 4 ways...

Comment: @Skr: be explicit and use `struct node *` instead of `NODE`. It's more readable, IMHO.

Answer (score 18):

It defines `NODE` as a synonym for the type `struct node *`, so when you'll be declaring a variable of type `NODE` you'll be actually declaring a pointer to `struct node`.

Personally, I don't think that such declaration is a good idea: you're "hiding a pointer" (which is almost always a bad idea), and, moreover, you are not highlighting this fact in any way into the new name.

Comment: +1 for the same reason. Naming it `nodeptr` instead of `node` would help, but then there's no reason to `typedef` it at all.

Comment: "Don't hide pointer types behind a typedef" what do you mean by this

Comment: He means that with that `typedef` you'll be working with a pointer type (`struct node *`) without making it evident to one that first reads your code (who just sees `NODE`, and probably assumes it's not a pointer).

Answer (score 7):

It makes `NODE` a typedef for a `struct node *`.

Comment: what would be a better way to write this code...retaining the same meaning.

Comment: A better way would be to omit the typedef, and refer to the pointer type as `struct node *`.

Answer (score 7):

`NODE` becomes an alias for `struct node*`.

---

EDIT: Okay, for the comment (if I write my answer as comment, it would be too long and not formatted):

There's no different way to write this. Here, `typedef` is used just to create a synonym/alias for *pointer* to `struct node`.
An example for usage would be:

```
void f()
{
    // some code
    NODE p = NULL;
    // do something with p
    // for example use malloc and so on
    // like: p = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    // and access like: p->coef = ..; p->expr = ..
    // do something with p and free the memory later (if malloc is used)
}
```

is the same as

```
void f()
{
    // some code
    struct node* p = NULL;
    // do something with p
}
```

Using `NODE` makes it just shorter (anyway, I wouldn't advise such `typedef`, as you're hiding, that it's a *pointer*, not a `struct` or other type, as mentioned in @Matteo Italia's answer).

---

The format, you're referring: "typedef struct{}type_name format" is something else. It's kind of a trick in `C`, to avoid writing `struct` keyword (as it's obligatory in `C`, and NOT in `C++`). So

```
typedef struct node
{
    //..
} NODE;
```

would make `NODE` alias for `struct node`. So, the same example as above:

```
void f()
{
    // some code
    NODE p;
    // do something with p
    // note that now p is automatically allocated, it's real struct
    // not a pointer. So you can access its members like:
    // p.coef or p.expr, etc.
}
```

is the same as

```
void f()
{
    // some code
    struct node p;
    // do something with p
}
```

NOTE that now, `p` is ***NOT*** a pointer, it's `struct node`.

Comment: can u write the same code in different way. how to write the same code in typedef struct{}type_name; format???

Comment: "typedef struct{}type_name format" using this format how can i make NODE as a pointer.would it be like this typedef struct node*{}NODE;

Comment: No, you should put the `*` after the definition of the struct, like this: `typedef struct node { /* sth */ } *NODE;`. You can even make 2 types like this (and I'd recommend that): `typedef struct node { /* sth */ } NODE, *NODE_PTR`, where `NODE` will be `typedef` for `struct node` and `NODE_PTR` will be `typedef` for `struct node*`.

Comment: @Skr - if this answered your question, you might want to accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

simply tells you can create pointer of  node type using only NODE every time instead of writting struct node * everytime

Answer (score -4):

> what does `typedef struct node *NODE` indicate?

**UPPERCASE IS NO GOOD**

Reserve **ALL UPPERCASE** identifiers for **MACROS**.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's a good idea to let `NODE` contains `*`