# Typedef struct declared as two types: "typedef struct x { .. } X, *XPointer"

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Sorry if this has been asked before, I wasn't really even sure what to search for to come up with this.

When I create a `typedef struct`, I usually do something like this:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
  int a;
  int b;
  struct myStruct *next;
} MyStruct;
```

So I declare it with `MyStruct` at the end.  Then when I create functions that pass that in as a parameter, I write

```
int doSomething(MyStruct *ptr){

}
```

Yet I am collaborating with a friend on a project and I have come across his coding style, which is to *also* declare `*MyStructP` like this:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
  int a;
  int b;
  struct myStruct *next;
} MyStructR, *MyStructP;
```

And then he uses `MyStructP` in his functions, so his parameters look like:

```
int doSomething(MyStructP)
```

So he doesn't have to use the `*` in the parameter list.  This confused me because when I look at the parameter list, I always look for the `*` to determine if the arg is a pointer or not.  On top of that, I am creating a function that takes in a struct I created and a struct he created, so my arg has the * and his does not. Ultra confusing!!

Can someone give insight/comparison/advice on the differences between the two? Pros? Cons? Which way is better or worse, or more widely used? Any information at all. Thanks!

Comment: @hvd Sorry that was a typo. It should read *if the arg is a pointer or not*

Comment: @krb686 Thanks, that makes a lot more sense. Still, in `void f(int a[], int b())`, both `a` and `b` are pointers. You do have syntax there to indicate that something special is going on, though.

Comment: they are the same. compiler won't even complain anything. maybe you can try to search `*` and type names end with `P` as pointer.

Comment: @hvd Thanks yeah I think I have that down, such as how these are the same: `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941313/what-does-typedef-struct-node-node-indicate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) says to avoid these kinds of typedefs:

> #### Chapter 5: Typedefs
>
> Please don't use things like "vps_t".
>
> It's a *mistake* to use typedef for structures and pointers. When you see a
>
> ```
> vps_t a;
> ```
>
> in the source, what does it mean?
>
> In contrast, if it says
>
> ```
> struct virtual_container *a;
> ```
>
> you can actually tell what "a" is.

Comment: That's funny, we also went back and forth a bit the other day about that as well.  I agree completely, and I brought up the inconvenience that when using `typedef`, it makes future instantiations uncolored in vim!!

Answer (score 12):

It is generally considered poor style to hide pointers behind typedefs, unless they are meant to be opaque handles (for example `SDL_GLContext` is a `void*`).
This being not the case here, I agree with you that it's more confusing than helping.

Answer (score 4):

Some people like to go with ideas from [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) when they name variables. And some people take that concept further when they name types.

I think it's a matter of taste.

However, I think it obscures things (like in your example) because you'd have to dig up the *declaration* of the *name* in order to find its type. I prefer things to be obvious and explicit, and I would avoid such type names.

(And remember, [`typedef`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) does not introduce a new type but merely a new name that aliases a new type.)

Comment: exactly what I was thinking! If I'm in another file calling his functions, I have to look for the declaration if I'm confused.  And sure I guess it's good he adds "P" at the end, but it just makes me realize someone could choose to not do that, and then it'd be really bad!

Answer (score 2):

The main good reason why people occasionally typedef pointers is to represent the type as a "black box object" to the programmer and to allow its implementation to more easily be changed in the future.

For example, maybe today the type is a pointer to a struct but tomorrow the type becomes an index into some table, a handle/key of some sort, or a file descriptor.  Typedef'ing this way tells the programmer that they shouldn't try things they might normally do to a pointer such as comparing it against 0 / NULL, dereferencing it (e.g. - directly accessing members), incrementing it, etc., as their code may become broken in the future.  Of course, using a naming convention, such as your friend did, that reveals and encodes that the underlying implementation actually is a pointer conflicts with that purpose.

The other reason to do this is to make this kind of error less likely:

```
myStructR *ptr1, ptr2;
myStructP  ptr3, ptr4;
```

That's pretty weak sauce as the compiler will typically catch you misusing `ptr2` later, but that is a reason given for doing this.

Comment: not really true,  the thing that should be modified is the actual struct definition.  Nothing else needs any changing (except possibly code to access individual fields in the struct.)  I.E.  abusing the typedef facility leads to confusion.  In this case, (typedef a struct) is a bad idea.  It just clutters the namespace, obscures the code, and makes for maintenance nightmares

Comment: @user3629249 If the type is meant to be an opaque "reference" or "handle" to an object, where the implementation of such a "reference" can change as I suggested, then why would you force that reference to be wrapped in another type and then a pointer to that wrapper to be passed around instead?